# Should I use noexcept specifier and noexcept operator in most functions in C++?

Tags: c++, function, throw, noexcept

I'm still new to the C++ programming language, and I'm trying to learn new things.

I'm implementing a very very basic iterator/reverse_iterator classes and other standard library containers.

I see in most standard library implementations like GCC, MS, and others that they use the `noexcept` specifier and `noexcept` operator in the majority of their functions to test if they throw or not.

This is one example:

```
_GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR
        reverse_iterator(const reverse_iterator<_Iter>& __x)
    _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT_IF(noexcept(_Iterator(__x.current)))
    : current(__x.current)
    { }

_GLIBCXX_NODISCARD
      _GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR iterator_type
      base() const
      _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT_IF(noexcept(_Iterator(current)))
      { return current; }
```

But, there are parts where they don't use them, like this:

```
template<typename _Iterator>
    _GLIBCXX_NODISCARD
    inline _GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR bool
    operator==(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
           const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __y)
    { return __x.base() == __y.base(); }
```

I know that if a function is marked as `noexcept`, the compiler can perform some optimizations, and also know that only needs to be used where you know the function (or calls to other functions inside) cannot throw exceptions.

As until I understand, here is used because we're working with templates, and we're testing if the type does or doesn't throw (please correct me if I'm wrong).

So, in what situations do I need to test for no-throwing with `noexcept` specifier and `noexcept` operator in functions?

And, from the example above with the comparison operator, why don't they use `noexcept`?

Can I mark those comparison operators `noexcept` or test if they are `noexcept`?

Comment: If your function can't throw, feel free to use it. Personally, I have the compiler issue warnings when there's functions which can be marked `noexcept` which currently aren't. `noexcept` operator tends to be needed with templates though, since sometimes it depends on the type of data.

Comment: Ok. And what about with the comparison operators? Why the implementers didn't mark them as `noexcept`? They already tested the `base()` member function that is used inside of it and is `noexcept`. So, why not bothering to mark operator==() `noexcept` too?

Comment: q.v. https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Re-noexcept

Comment: Thanks. I read that guideline before. I only don't understand, from the examples in my question, if the `base()` is tested as `noexcept`, why the `operator==`, which is using the same `base()` is not using `noexcept` or testing if noexcept?

Comment: @Eljay Love the discussion linked by the guideline. Astoundingly informative.

Comment: Yes, great information. I agree with you. I think I must have to read again more carefully.

Comment: Some random thoughts: If you were to compare iterators into different containers, that would be UB, and cannot easily be `noexcept` (or compile time tested if it is). Some implementations reserve the right to throw exceptions for this in debug mode.

Comment: Consider this: if you omit `noexcept` everywhere, the code should work correctly, but there may be some things (like `std::vector`) that have to use copy instead of move to maintain its contractual invariants — so a perf hit.  The use of `noexcept` needs to be done carefully, and intentionally.  And sometimes intentionally used as a "if an exception percolates up to here, terminate the app".

Comment: After doing some research in various blogs and websites about the usage of `noexcept` I encounter great information about considerations for when to use it, I decided to answer my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research on several websites and found great information that expanded my knowledge in the `noexcept` usage.

After reading the *Andrzej's C++ blog*. [Using noexcept](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/using-noexcept/) I understood how does `noexcept` work better and when to use it and when to avoid it.

From the examples that I introduced in my question, I wanted to know why, in this particular case, the `operator==` is not using `noexcept` if is well known that mark a function/constructor as `noexcept` the compiler can perform some optimization and I ended with the conclusion that there is no performance gain if I use it in that particular function.

In other words, the `operator==` don't need the `noexcept` specification because no performance gain is used for the code itself because there are no move-like operations involved or other kind of no-throw exceptions guarantees that are needed. And finally, the `operator==` is marked as `inline constexpr` that is going to inline the function where used, so that is a performance gain for that particular code.